# How to change block device names, e.g. /dev/sdc to /dev/sdb?

Tags: command-line, block-device

Example of why this might be desired: I connect a block device, which shows up as /dev/sdb, and mount it. Later that device gets removed without being unmounted. The block device is reconnected, but this time given the name /dev/sdc. I unmount /dev/sdb but then want to switch /dev/sdc to be /dev/sdb.

How can I do this from the command line on OpenSUSE 13.1, without using persistent names?

The purpose of the question is for fixing a problematic state, such as the example given, not as a workaround for deliberately doing something incorrectly (such as not unmounting). This is also why persistent names would not be a solution.

Comment: What distribution (and what version)?

Comment: @roaima OpenSUSE 13.1 (question updated)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mount hard drives in the same order in debian](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227141/mount-hard-drives-in-the-same-order-in-debian)

Comment: @Celada I would prefer a solution that doesn't rely on persistent names

Comment: @OwenPauling I understand. But the `sdX` names are assigned by the kernel as soon as the device is detected. Creating an alias for `sd<something>` under `<some-persistent-name>` is easy and clean. Trying to rename `sd<something>` to `sd<something-else>` on the other hand is problematic. What if the device name you want to rename *to* is already taken? Do you shuffle names around until they fit? And even if you succeed then the kernel and the `/dev` filesystem will have a different idea of what the name is, which can be confusing when consulting kernel logs.

Comment: @Celada Conceptually I was thinking it more like "move the device from /dev/sdc to /dev/sdb" rather than a rename. But I guess this is a lot more complex than I first thought.

Comment: I'm not sure what the different would be between "move device from `/dev/sdc` to `/dev/sdb`" and "rename device  from `/dev/sdc` to `/dev/sdb`". Also, remember the underlying reason why the kernel chose `sdc` in the first place instead of `sdb`. It's because `sda` and `sdb` were already taken at the time!

Comment: Note that you can't just move the device in /dev except for the most trivial of uses, because that doesn't move the entries in /sys/block, which are used by some programs to retrieve information about the device.  Unfortunately I'm still looking for how to move that part...

Comment: Can you use symlinks, like the ones in `/dev/disk/by-…`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, this looks like an A-B problem.